# mysql decimal and tinyint multiplication precision

Tags: mysql

In mysql 5.1, I have a table that include two columns

```
create table t1 {
  price decimal(6,2),
  quantity tinyint(4),
  ...
}
```

In a select query I am doing

```
select sum(price * quantity)
from t1
group by ...
```

Is this calculation a precise calculation (using fixed-point arithmetic)? or do I need to worry about rounding/precision loss etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there is no precise loss when multiply decimal with integer. See [Precision Math Examples](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/precision-math-examples.html). I also did a small experiment to see the different between float-point and decimal:

```
SELECT .1E0 * .1E0, 
       .1 * .1, 
       (.1E0 * .1E0) * 10, 
       (.1 * .1) * 10
```

The output is

```
0.010000000000000002          << .1E0 * .1E0
0.01                          << .1 * .1
0.10000000000000002           << (.1E0 * .1E0) * 10
0.10                          << (.1 * .1) * 10
```

Answer (score 2):

The computational result is perfectly good, and doesn't lose precision.

See here for example:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/173cf/1/0

But you may be headed for trouble with your tinyint(4). That has a range of [-128, 127] notwithstanding the (4).  See here. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html

Answer (score 0):

When multiplying a decimal with a precision of 2 by any integer (int or tinyint), you don't have to worry about losing any additional precision -- it will have no more than 2 decimal places in the result.