# How does we understand this float-point numbers (.1E0)

Tags: mysql, types, floating-point, numbers

It is about data types in mysql and floating-point values, but I don't understand that format.
[example:](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-examples.html) `.1E0`
I know E means *10
what does means the `0` there?
What number that represent?[image]
another [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17635584/mysql-decimal-and-tinyint-multiplication-precision):
[image]

Comment: E0 means `10^0` (read 10 to zero power) which is `1`. So .`1E0` means `0.1 * 10^0 = 0.1 * 1 = 0.1`.. So `SELECT .1E0 = 0.1`  should return `1`

Comment: but I think you are wrong, because [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17635584/mysql-decimal-and-tinyint-multiplication-precision)

Comment: @christianbueno.1: `E0` does mean `times ten to the power of 0`, but I suspect there is some type or formatting issue involved. E.g., `.1` and `.1E0` may indicate different types, so one uses more precision or a different base. Something like that could explain the differences.